# How to disable the click sound of the iPhone Camera through code?

Tags: iphone

I have to disable the click sound of the iPhone Camera in my app. Please provide the code if possible?

Comment: I thought there were legal precedents for the click sound being made?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat You can disable the click sound by just toggling the mute switch on the side of the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

When the user presses the Click button or maybe when your app is launched, rename file /System/Library/Audio/UISounds/photoShutter.caf to maybe  /System/Library/Audio/UISounds/photoShutter1.caf

When the photo is done clicking, rename it back to original.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How to do that? Is it possible to change system sounds?